# Can't change the style of my bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have problems with my bibliography, currently I am using bibtex entries like this:

```
    @article{Tay,
    author = {F. E. H. Tay; L. J. Cao},
    title = {Improved financial time series forecasting by
    combining Support Vector Machines with
    self-organizing feature map},
    journaltitle = {Intelligent Data Analysis},
    date = {2001},
    volume = {5},
    pages = {339-354},
    }
```

But for some reason it compiles into

```
F. E. H. Tay; L. J. Cao. Improved financial time series forecasting by combining support vector machines with self-organizing feature map. 5:339–354.
```

There is no year and journaltitle! And this is my problem, I need them.

Currently I am using

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

but changing it to other styles had no effect at all, I mean there was no change in bibliography entries, for some reason this command just do not work.

It would be nice, if anyone could somehow help me to resolve this problem. I am using TexStudio.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the `date` field to `year`, and `journaltitle` to `journal`? (After making the changes, be sure tu rerun bibtex and then LateX twice more to fully propagate the change.) Incidentally, you should use 'and` as the separator between authors.

Comment: If you change the style in your Latex file, you need to run latex, then run bibtex, then run latex again before you will see any change...

Comment: @Thruston - that's good advice.  However, since the `plain` bibliography style doesn't recognize the field names `date` and `journal`, it won't help the OP all that much.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mico! Your advice helped to solve the issue, and thank you for suggestion on using 'and', now my bibliography is sorted properly. Is there any way to say you thanks by +rep or something like this? Or at least mark your comment as helpful?

Comment: How about if I re-post my comment as an answer? :-) You can then accept and/or upvote it.

Comment: Let us do it!
btw maybe there is some name instead of "location", so i could get location visible in the bibliography?

Comment: Have you tried "address"?

Comment: That helped, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BibTeX's `plain` bibliography style as well as virtually all other BibTeX-based bibliography styles do not recognize -- and hence do not process -- fields named `date` and `journaltitle`. Use `year` and `journal` instead.

Separately, you should use the keyword `and` as the separator between authors. The term `and` is a keyword in `author` fields; don't use `;` (semicolon).

The result of a full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{demobib.bib}
@article{Tay,
    author  = {F. E. H. Tay and L. J. Cao},
    title   = {Improved financial time series forecasting by
               combining Support Vector Machines with
               self-organizing feature map},
    journal = {Intelligent Data Analysis},
    year    = {2001},
    volume  = {5},
    pages   = {339-354},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\cite{Tay}
\bibliography{demobib}
\end{document}
```